# Cloudformation wildcard search with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I have been tasked with converting some bash scripting used by my team that performs various cloudformation tasks into Python using the boto3 library. I am currently stuck on one item. I cannot seem to determine how to do a wildcard type search where a cloud formation stack name contains a string.

My bash version using the AWS CLI is as follows:

```
aws cloudformation --region us-east-1 describe-stacks --query "Stacks[?contains(StackName,'myString')].StackName" --output json > stacks.out
```

This works on the cli, outputting the results to a json file, but I cannot find any examples online to do a similar search for contains using boto3 with Python. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. What you are looking for is the following:

```
import boto3

# create a boto3 client first
cloudformation = boto3.client('cloudformation', region_name='us-east-1')

# use client to make a particular API call
response = cloudformation.describe_stacks(StackName='myString')
print(response)

# as an aside, you'd need a different client to communicate
# with a different service
# ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
# regions = ec2.describe_regions()
```

where, `response` is a Python dictionary, which, among other things, will contain the description of the stack, "myString".